# Почему дважды срабатывает один и тотже скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

собствено вот этот скрипт

```
$('#formMenu').submit(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert('yes');
        //oData = new FormData(form);
        console.log(ev);
    });
```

при клике на `input type ='submit'` событие  `.submit()` срабатывает два раза причем оба раза ev  получает разные объекты  вот что получаю первый раз

```
Object {
 originalEvent: submit,
 type: "submit", 
 isDefaultPrevented: returnTrue(),
 timeStamp: 0,
 jQuery22406012973310565117: true,
 which: undefined,
 view: undefined,
 target: <form#formMenu>,
 shiftKey: undefined,
 relatedTarget: undefined,
 ещё 13… }
```

вот что второй раз получаю

```
Object { 
 type: "submit",
 timeStamp: 1497342808303,
 jQuery22406012973310565117: true,
 isTrigger: 3,
 namespace: "",
 rnamespace: null,
 result: true,
 target: <form#formMenu>,
 delegateTarget: <form#formMenu>,
 currentTarget: <form#formMenu>,
 ещё 3… }
```

не объясните почему так и как продебажить ошибку

Comment: я так думаю кнопочка на форме имеет тип submit?

Comment: @Artsiom ага и что ?

Comment: сорри, не видел твоего коммента про submit( Попробуй назначть отправку просто на обычную кнопку и там уже submit обрабатывай. Плюс еще как вариант возвращай true в каллбэке

Comment: Попробуйте изменить тип input type ='button' , а тут сделать $('#formMenu').click(function() {

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov А по другому не вариант?

Comment: @Sergalas у меня была проблема такого же характера при вызове web-сервиса, тоже использовал submit и начинался цикл из 2-5 повторов (( исправил на button и все заработало корректно, может кто-то еще что предложит ))

Comment: Попробовал, у меня срабатывает один раз. HTML:
`<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formMenu">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
  $('#formMenu').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('yes');
    //oData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(ev);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @DmitryTaipov я вас честно от всего сердца поздравляю но у тысячей пользователей нет к примеру вот один из рецептов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery

Comment: @Sergalas 1) В вашем комментарии не хватает слов. Чего нет у тысячей пользователей? 2) Из вопроса не понятно, что проблема состоит в двойном нажатии на кнопку submit

Comment: @DmitryTaipov вроде я не писал что дважды нажимаюна кнопку submit обрабытывается она дважды основной совет поменять с input type='submit' на button это не то что бы проблема просто не хотелось лишние костыли в фраимворке настраивать вот решил попробовать один из советов.

Comment: @Sergalas а в каком браузере не работает? Проверил на Chrome, FF, IE11 . Вот еще fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m3pb3evt/
Можно ли посмотреть целиком html c js, где при нажатии на кнопку submit, событие submit() вызывается два раза?

Comment: @DmitryTaipov хорошо согласен везде один а у меня два причем два разных объекта лежит в ev  почему вызывается два раза вот ведь в чем вопрос. И как можно понять откуда идет вызов второй раз. Учитывая что объекты разные